# Inequality with logs and without

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I somehow need to solve this inequality:

$$\frac{a}{\rho a-b}\ln\rho-\frac{1}{\rho}\ln\frac{\rho a-b}{a-b}<0$$

where I know that

$a>b>1$

$1>\rho>0$

$\rho a>b$

Either I need to show that it is always fulfilled or the condition on $\rho$ that makes it true.

I tried various ways, but I always get stuck at the problem of having $\rho$ in the $\ln$ expression and outside of it. I also tried it via $\log_{\rho}\frac{\rho a-b}{a-b}$, to no avail. If necessary I can put an upper limit on $a$. Throwing the computer at it in all parameter constellations that were relevant for me, showed it was true, but that's not a proof, of course...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = a/b > 1$ and $\rho x > 1$ then you have (multiply through with $\rho$) equivalently
$$
F(x,\rho) = \frac{\rho x}{\rho x-1}\ln\rho-\ln\frac{\rho x-1}{x-1}<0
$$
Note that for any choice of $x$, $F(x,\rho=1) = 0$. So you just have to check whether $F(x,\rho)$ is increasing for $0 < \rho < 1$ for all $x$, since this means that $F(x,\rho)$ increases with $\rho$ towards $0$, so it is then negative everywhere. Taking
$$
\frac{\partial F(x,\rho)}{\partial \rho} = \frac{- x \log(\rho)}{(-1 + \rho x)^2} > 0
$$
which proves the claim.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but when differentiating $F$, did you forget the second term? I get $$\frac{\partial F(x,\rho)}{\partial\rho}=-\frac{x\ln\rho}{(\rho x-1)^2}-x\frac{x-1}{\rho x-1}$$

Comment: @Andreas Your derivative of the first term is incomplete, it should read $\frac{x (-1 + x \rho - \log(\rho))}{(-1 + \rho x)^2}$. If you then combine with your derivative of the second term, you get the result.

Comment: Oh my... Senior moment here. I can only assume, I need a break... Thanks a lot for your help.